# java, loading of resources fails: unable to resolve file:/my-jar.jar!/folder/my-file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, resources

From a java application i made, I build the corresponding jar file.

I copy all the resources in the jar file.

For example, if in `src/main/resources` there exists the following resource `/folder/my-file`, then it's copied in the jar with the same path.

But if i execute the jar, the loading of the resources fails.

Specifically, it throws an IOException like this

> java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve
>   "file:/my-jar.jar!/folder/my-file" as either class path, filename or
>   URL

How should I load the resources?

If I run the java app in eclipse, all works fine, even the resources are loaded correctly.

EDIT:

I'm getting the path of the resource via:

```
 MyClass.class.getResource("/folder/my-file").getPath();
```

The loading of the resource is made by an external library, what i have to d is just specify the path.

Answer (score 3):

In that case, I would try:

```
YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("folder/my-file");
```

Which would return an `InputStream` to your resource independently of your execution environment  .

Comment: In this case i would add an `/` but apart from that it's exactly what will work.

Comment: I didn't specify it in the question, but i need the path of the resource, and i'm getting it via MyClass.class.getResource("/folder/my-file").getPath();
so I don't think your solution will be ok, do you agree?

Comment: I do not know what exactly are you doing with your resource, do you need its path for a specific reason or do you just need to read it?  Because if you only need to read it, the most straight-forward and decoupled solution is accessing it via classloader and getting an InputStream from it - no path or execution-dependent elements involved

Comment: I need just the path.

Comment: But depending on your deployment type (for example, a .war) you may have not an usable path to that resource.  Please consider deploy it to a know directory in your machine (and leave the path in a .properties file, for example)

Comment: @GiovanniBitliner You need just the path why? The input stream is all you should need. Resources are not files, and JAR files are not directories.

Answer (score -1):

if you have an structure like this:

```
src/main/Begin.java
src/main/folder/icon.png
```

Try this in the Begin.java:

```
  Begin.getClass().getResource("/main/folder/icon.png");
```

Comment: Have you tried this? `main` won't be there at runtime.